# Wcat and Jenkins (Hudson)

Tags: jenkins, wcat

We have [WCAT](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6) based load tests. Now we want to use Jenkins continuous integration tool. What we want to see is a trend graph of "requests/sec" metric.
I didn't find any suitable plugin in [plugins page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) to achieve this.

Could anyone suggest me solution except to write my own plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the WCAT data into CSV format, the [Plot plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) should work for you.

Comment: I should add that this plugin supports not only CSV format but XML as well.

Comment: I just wasted half an hour or more trying to figure out why my graphs are not displaying. As it turned out this plugin does not allow spaces in plot group name.